# The activity doesn't start on the emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-logcat

The console shows starting activity but the activity doesn't open in the emulator. Also, the logcat runs continuously.

```
[2015-01-09 10:41:33 - ODCH_MIS] Android Launch!
[2015-01-09 10:41:33 - ODCH_MIS] adb is running normally.
[2015-01-09 10:41:33 - ODCH_MIS] Performing com.empover.odch.fragments.LoginActivity activity launch
[2015-01-09 10:41:34 - ODCH_MIS] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD '7Inch' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554'
[2015-01-09 10:41:34 - ODCH_MIS] Uploading ODCH_MIS.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2015-01-09 10:41:35 - ODCH_MIS] Installing ODCH_MIS.apk...
[2015-01-09 10:42:47 - ODCH_MIS] Success!
[2015-01-09 10:42:47 - ODCH_MIS] Starting activity com.empover.odch.fragments.LoginActivity on device emulator-5554
```

Comment: Go to menu and see if your application is present there as it was successfully installed.

Comment: @PsyDuck I am working in eclipse and the app has not been installed.

Comment: `[2015-01-09 10:41:35 - ODCH_MIS] Installing ODCH_MIS.apk...
[2015-01-09 10:42:47 - ODCH_MIS] Success!` This tells you that it has been installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

> Increase Ram for the virtual device and try to select a old device with small screen to emulate , between some times the  screen may take up to a minute to load depending in your computer

Hope this will Help..